# Laravel PHP: Custom code write location

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

This is my first day on Laravel framework. I have prior experience in CodeIgniter framework.

I am creating very basic application to start with Laravel. I want to create user registration application. I want to know which is the best and/or other locations where I can put my code into. **I have gone throgh the Laravel documents, but want to know the standards that other programmers are following.**

Model : Files dealing with database

View : Files mostly containing HTML

Controller : Where all business logic resides

UI : CSS, Javascript, Custom javascript libraries

Comment: what you mean custom code?

Comment: fyi, Laravel has [buit-in user authentication/login/registration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication). Models in `/app/`, Views in `/resources/views/`, controllers in `/app/Http/Controllers/` and css/js in `/resources/assets/scss/` / `/resources/assets/js/`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running

```
php artisan make:auth
```

It will create the controllers routes and views model, so you get a clear idea on how you would do a custom registration! :D